# Write a function that returns a slice of interfaces in Golang

Tags: sql, go

In Golang the `Scanner` interface takes a single `dest` argument, which is any number of `interface{}`s:

```
// Scan copies the columns in the current row into the values pointed at by dest.
func (rs *Rows) Scan(dest ...interface{}) error
```

Is there an alternative function that can return a slice of interfaces as its result? Say I wanted to put the `dest` arguments in a function, so I didn't have to write them out every time.

```
func scanArgs() []interface{} {

}

func main() {
    db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM users").Scan(scanArgs()...)
}
```

I've tried this but I'm running into issues with the method signature; I can set a `[]interface` as the return value, but I can't easily create one inside the function. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily allocate inside the function with syntax like the following;

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        objs := &[]interface{}{} 
        objs2 := make([]interface{}, 10)
        objs3 := []interface{}{}
    fmt.Println(len(*objs))
    fmt.Println(len(objs2))
    fmt.Println(len(objs3))
}
```

Since everything implements the empty interface you can add any type to those collections with `append`. The init syntax is a bit clunky and probably what's throwing you... The reason it looks like that is because I'm declaring the type `interface{}` there when typically you'd have the name of an *actual* interface like `[]io.Writer{}`. Instead you need those extract curlys.